# Loading geospatial datasets with rioxarray

Tags: python, rasterio, rioxarray, xarray

I'm using xarray to open and reproject some .grib files. The files have x, y, and time dimensions and contain several data variables. However, I have some issues with loading the data.

Loading them with xarray's load_dataset method returns the dataset correctly, but (expectedly) looses the geo metadata (like crs or transformation parameters) from the grib files.

```py
import xarray as xr
xds= xr.load_dataset('data.grib', chunks='auto')
print(xds)
```

returns

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (time: 142, y: 1069, x: 1069)
Coordinates:
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-01-05 ... 2018-12-30T12:00:00
    latitude    (y, x) float64 20.29 20.31 20.32 20.34 ... 63.84 63.81 63.77
    longitude   (y, x) float64 342.5 342.6 342.6 342.6 ... 73.97 74.04 74.11
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
Data variables:
    var         (time, y, x) float32 0.9846 -1.39 0.2346 ... 111.4 109.1 104.6
```

rioxarray's read_rasterio method correctly loads the metadata, but returns a data array and treats all data variables and my time dimension as bands (in one single dimension)

```py
import rioxarray as rxr
xds_rio= rxr.open_rasterio('data.grib', masked=True, chunks='auto')
print(xds_rio)
```

returns

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 426, y: 1069, x: 1069)>
dask.array<open_rasterio-f5ca7fd5347911fe234d9f6d01ed726e<this-array>, shape=(426, 1069, 1069), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1, 1069, 1069), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 420 421 422 423 424 425 426
  * x            (x) float64 -2.937e+06 -2.932e+06 ... 2.931e+06 2.937e+06
  * y            (y) float64 2.937e+06 2.931e+06 ... -2.932e+06 -2.937e+06
    spatial_ref  int64 0
```

How can I load this data correctly, including geo metadata and data variables?